# How to make a loop that keeps cheking if theres a certain class

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I'm trying to make a loop that keeps searching for a class with "buy" and if it finds it needs to refresh until it can't find it anymore and then it runs the rest of the code. I'm using selenium and python help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
foundButton = False
    while not foundButton:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "buy")    
        if (driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "buy")):
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.refresh()
            driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "buy")
        else:
            foundButton = True
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I editied the question thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not `true` is the actual loop condition. The value must be true.

while(condition) or if(condition) implies do the action if condition evaluates to true. while not means do it if the condition is false. but because your initial value is false, the not negates it to true and ultimately the loop bever executes because the falseButton is false and the loop condition interprest as true always.

I always advise against using `boolean` values to control loop conditions because especially in python it is easy to confuse *outer* logic with *inner* logic. What I mean is that

```
while (condition)
while [not (condition)]
```

No matter what the outcome is, for the while to proceed, the cumulative outcome must be true always.

Comment: Surely you mean it must be false for it to loop

Comment: yes. what im trying to say is that the condition while whatever (condition) must evaluate to true always.

Comment: the not at front simply negates it.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you meant. The entire proposition must evaluate to true of course.

Comment: sorry i am unable to put it into words properly. please edit my abswer to improve on it. thank you.

Comment: I removed the not from while not if that's what you mean but it's still not looping.

Comment: no @koeliga thats not it. your main mistake was using boolean here. the ultimate condition must me true. therefore the initial value of falsebutton must be true.

Comment: why dont you change falsebutton to 0 instead and ```while (falsebutton == 0)``` then later change it to 1

Comment: sorry im referring to foundButton not falsebutton

Comment: or you can explicitly do ```while(foundButton == False)```. the point is that the ultimate outcome has to be true always

Comment: @mindoverflow Thanks for your help it worked. Have nice day. I'm just starting to code and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. it is best to use int for loop conditions variables. then we don't have to worry about micro logic. when we're doing bigger projects, this might create issues. it is also good practice to always explicitly declare conditions ```while (something == something_else)``` instead of relying on final evaluation like ```while(expression)```. good luck!